# How to signal to Django when inserting data using custom SQL in psycopg2?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

When using psycopg2 in order to write data to a postgres database, the data is inserted no problem, however django does not seem to realise it has occurred. There are no signals sent as far as I can tell. My (generic) code for inserting using psycopg2 is shown below:

```py
conn = psycopg2.connect(.....)
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ......)
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

I have been looking into NOTIFY in postgres, but can't seem to have any luck.

Would appreciate if anyone has any advice for this problem and can show me how to send a signal when an INSERT occurs.

Perhaps I should explore NOTIFY in postgres?

Expected result is a post_save signal maybe?

Comment: post_save signal are called by the ORM model instance. You cannot expect that to work when performing an insert directly on the database. Maybe this gist (https://gist.github.com/pkese/2790749) is something in the direction you want?

Comment: send the signal manually yourself in your code. [This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/signals/#defining-and-sending-signals) is how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your help both. I managed to get it working with a custom django signal that triggers after every psycopg2 insert as opposed to an actual notification from postgres itself.